# Typecasting from struct to LPVOID

Tags: c++, memory, struct, casting

Worked fine before I threw it into a class. Any help for resolving this typecasting error?

**Error**

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'IAT CInjector::* ' to 'LPVOID'
```

**Code Referenced**

```
WriteProcessMemory(CInjector::_hProc, 
    CInjector::_iatBaseAddress, 
    (LPVOID) & CInjector::_iat, // typecasting error?
    sizeof (IAT), 
    NULL);
```

**Class**

```
class CInjector
{
private:
    ...
    IAT _iat;
    ...
}
```

**Typedef**

```
typedef struct _IAT {
    PLOADLIBRARYA pLoadLibraryA;
    PGETPROCADDRESS pGetProcAddress;
    FNMESSAGEBOX fnMessageBox;
} IAT;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `&CInjector::_iat` is a pointer-to-class-member, not a real pointer.  Since `_iat` isn't static, each class has its own copy of it, and so `&CInjector::_iat` is not an address, but rather is typically an offset into a class.  You can use it with the "pointer-to-member-selection" operator `.*`:

```
CInjector myCInjector;
IAT CInjector::* ptr = &CInjector::_iat;
myCInjector.*ptr = /* ... */
```

The C++ standard prohibits conversions between pointers-to-class-members and raw pointers because often they look different in memory - pointers-to-class-members often store some offset value so that they work correctly in multiple inheritance or in the presence of virtual functions, for example.

To fix this, you probably want to do one of two things.  First, you can mark `CInjector::_iat` `static`, which means that there's only one copy of it.  Consequently, `&CInjector::_iat` now refers to a concrete object, which is indeed a regular pointer, and the above code will work.  Second, you can get a concrete instance of `CInjector` and then take the address of its `_iat` field.  Since this refers to a specific object's field, you'll get back a raw pointer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: /facepalm; well, it's a singleton anyway, so I'll just throw static keywords in there. Thanks for the information about "pointer-to-member-selections" though.

Comment: @Gio Borje- If it's a singleton, you could just take the address of the singleton's `_iat` field.  That's always a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert pointer to member into a pointer to an object. [Read more here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=142).